# Using perl hash for comparing columns of 2 files

Tags: perl

I have asked this question(sorry for asking again, this time it is different and difficult) but I have tried a lot but did not achieve the results.

I have 2 big files (tab delimited).

first file ->

```
Col1           Col2    Col3 Col4     Col5        Col6       Col7    Col8
101_#2          1       H    F0       263        278        2       1.5
102_#1          1       6    F1       766        781        1       1.0
103_#1          2       15   V1       526        581        1       0.0
103_#1          2       9    V2       124        134        1       1.3
104_#1          1       12   V3       137        172        1       1.0
105_#1          1       17   F2       766        771        1       1.0
```

second file ->

```
Col1    Col2    Col3             Col4
97486   H   262               279
67486   9   118           119
87486   9   183           185
248233  9   124           134
```

If col3 value/character (of file1) and col2 value/character (of file 2) are same and then compare col5 and col6 of file 1(like a range value) with col3 and col4 of file2, if range of file 1 is present in file 2 then return that row (from file1) and also add the extra column1 from file2 in output.

Expected output ->

```
Col1      Col2    Col3 Col4     Col5        Col6       Col7    Col8   Col9
101_#2        1       H    F0       263        278        2       1.5       97486
103_#1        2       9    V2       124        134        1       1.3       248233
```

So far I have tried something with hashes->

```
@ARGV or die "No input file specified";
open my $first, '<',$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
open my $second,'<', $ARGV[1] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
print scalar (<$first>);
while(<$second>){
    chomp;
    @line=split /\s+/;
    $hash{$line[2]}=$line[3];
}
while (<$first>) {
    @cols = split /\s+/;
    $p1 = $cols[4];
    $p2 = $cols[5];
    foreach $key (sort keys %hash){
        if ($p1>= "$key"){
            if ($p2<=$hash{$key})
            {
                print join("\t",@cols),"\n";
            }
        }
        else{ next; }
    }
}
```

But there is no comparison of col3 value/character (of file1) and col2 value/character (of file 2)in above code.
But this is also taking lot of time and memory.Can anybody suggest how I can make it fast using hashes or hashes of hashes.Thanks a lot.

Hello everyone,

Thanks a lot for your help. I figured out an efficient way for my own question.

```
@ARGV or die "No input file specified";
open $first, '<',$ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
open $second,'<', $ARGV[1] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
print scalar (<$first>);


while(<$second>){
chomp;
@line=split /\s+/;

    $hash{$line[1]}{$line[2]}{$line[3]}= $line[0];
    }
while (<$first>) {

    @cols = split /\s+/;

foreach  $key1 (sort keys %hash) {
   foreach $key2 (sort keys %{$hash{$key1}}) {
        foreach  $key3 (sort keys %{$hash{$key1}{$key2}}) {
        if (($cols[2] eq $key1) && ($cols[4]>=$key2) && ($cols[5]<=$key3)){
            print join("\t",@cols),"\t",$hash{$key1}{$key2}{$key3},"\n";

        }   
        last;
    }

}
}
}
```

Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two hash tables. You just need one hash table built from entries in the first file, and when you loop through the second file, check if there's a key in the first-file hash table using `defined`.

If there is a key, do your comparisons on the values of other columns (we store values from the first file in the hash table for the third column's key).

If there's no key, then either `warn`, `die`, or have the script just keep going without saying anything, if that's what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $firstHashRef;

open FIRST, "< $firstFile" or die "could not open first file...\n";
while (<FIRST>) { 
    chomp $_;
    my @elements = split "\t", $_;
    my $col3Val = $elements[2];  # Perl arrays are zero-indexed
    my $col5Val = $elements[4];
    my $col6Val = $elements[5];

    # keep the fifth and sixth column values on hand, for
    # when we loop through the second file...

    if (! defined $firstHashRef->{$col3Val}) { 
        $firstHashRef->{$col3Val}->{Col5} = $col5Val; 
        $firstHashRef->{$col3Val}->{Col6} = $col6Val; 
    }
}
close FIRST;

open SECOND, "< $secondFile" or die "could not open second file...\n";
while (<SECOND>) {
    chomp $_;
    my @elements = split "\t", $_;
    my $col2ValFromSecondFile = $elements[1];
    my $col3ValFromSecondFile = $elements[2];
    my $col4ValFromSecondFile = $elements[3];

    if (defined $firstHashRef->{$col2ValFromSecondFile}) {
        # we found a matching key
        # 1. Compare $firstHashRef->{$col2ValFromSecondFile}->{Col5} with $col3ValFromSecondFile
        # 2. Compare $firstHashRef->{$col2ValFromSecondFile}->{Col6} with $col4ValFromSecondFile
        # 3. Do something interesting, based on comparison results... (this is left to you to fill in)
    }
    else {
        warn "We did not locate entry in hash table for second file's Col2 value...\n";
    }
}
close SECOND;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using just `awk` for this -

```
awk '
NR==FNR && NR>1{a[$3]=$0;b[$3]=$5;c[$3]=$6;next} 
($2 in a) && ($3<=b[$2] && $4>=c[$2]) {print a[$2],$1}' file1 file2
```

#### Input Data:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file1
Col1           Col2    Col3 Col4     Col5        Col6       Col7    Col8
101_#2          1       H    F0       263        278        2       1.5
109_#2          1       H    F0       263        278        2       1.5
102_#1          1       6    F1       766        781        1       1.0
103_#1          2       15   V1       526        581        1       0.0
103_#1          2       9    V2       124        134        1       1.3
104_#1          1       12   V3       137        172        1       1.0
105_#1          1       17   F2       766        771        1       1.0

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file2
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
97486   H       262     279
67486   9       118     119
87486   9       183     185
248233  9       124     134
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
NR==FNR && NR>1{a[$3]=$0;b[$3]=$5;c[$3]=$6;next} 
($2 in a) && ($3<=b[$2] && $4>=c[$2]) {print a[$2],$1}' file1 file2
101_#2          1       H    F0       263        278        2       1.5 97486
103_#1          2       9    V2       124        134        1       1.3 248233
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But awk is giving only results for 1 row and also I am not so familiar with awk.

Comment: Do you have a different data set then the one provided above? The above dataset yields two rows of data as shown in your expected output.

Comment: Yes it is same but there are more rows. and some of the rows in file1 are exactly same (with different ID in col1 of file1), then the awk command is not giving both the rows, but only 1 row.

Comment: If it is ok with you can you give me some sample data for which it does not match. May be the awk solution needs some minor changes.

Comment: 109_#2          1       H    F0       263        278        2       1.5
I have inserted this line as 2nd row in file1.